# Why AtomicInteger is abstract in Kotlin? (it works fine in Java)

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit

I was trying to make something similar to [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava/CallArbiter.java)(actually you don't need to read the link to understand this question, it's just for reference), and I write this:

```
class CallArbiter: AtomicInteger { // error
  constructor(initialValue: Int) : super(initialValue)
  constructor() : super()
}
```

The compiler says:

> Error:(8, 1) Kotlin: Class 'CallArbiter' must be declared abstract or implement abstract base class member public abstract fun toByte(): Byte defined in java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

I can't figure out why it requires me to implement those methods. I didn't  see them in the `AtomicInteger` class. Everything is fine in Java.

Comment: it is a mapped type for Kotlin.

Comment: Yes, because `kotlin.Number` is mapped to `java.lang.Number`

Comment: Seems that you have faced this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16087

Comment: I think of an old Chinese saying:"Straight hooks,salty bait"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AtomicInteger` extends `java.lang.Number`, but in Kotlin this type is [mapped](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) to `kotlin.Number`.

In `kotlin.Number` these abstract methods are defined (which you can see in its [API](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html)):

`toByte`, `toInt`, `toChar` etc.

If you debug this line of code: `AtomicInteger(2).toByte()` you can see, that the method `java.lang.Number::byteValue` is used, this is done by using certain compiler techniques.